# Apacheds unable to start

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, git

While trying to start apacheds.service I am getting error like apacheds is not loading properly [image]

Comment: please don't post images of text

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The package has not been installed correctly. You can try to fix the installation with:

```
sudo apt-get -f install apacheds
```

You also have the option to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove apacheds
sudo apt-get install apacheds
```

Or just reconfigure it:

```
sudo dpkg reconfigure apacheds
```

Depending on the result of these commands you may be able to figure out what's the issue, or if you're lucky, one of these will just fix it.

Comment: Psst!  Launchpad bug #1646146.